# Can someone explain to me what's snell envelope?

Tags: option-pricing

What is snell intuitively? And what is its use in quantitative finance?
Please explain to me as intuitive as possible!

As I explained in the comments, I am new to this field and I was hoping someone can explain this concept in a more intuitive way, like how you are going to explain this concept to someone without the background knowledge? Doesn't have to be long or detailed, just on the very high level what does it do...

Thanks.

Comment: You can google it, I believe.

Comment: Agreed with Gordon, the downvote is mine. Please show some effort.

Comment: Of course I already googled it, but all the sources gave tons of formulas, I don't have a mathematical background so it was difficult for me to read the notes. And as I asked I want someone to explain in a more intuitive way.

Comment: Like if you have to explain this concept to someone without a mathematical background, how are you going to approach it?

Comment: Reverted, thanks to the background you added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 5pm you get in your car and drive down a highway that has multiple exits: exit 1, exit 2, exit 3 etc. The objective is to get home a quickly as possible, i.e to Maximize -T, where T is the time you arrive home.. Let's say if you take Exit 1 you can be home at 6:30, if you take exit 2 you can be home at 6:15, if you take exit 3 6pm and if you take exit 4 at 6:45pm. Clearly the optimal solution is to take exit 3. The Snell function tells you the best you can do as you approach each exit, assuming you make the best choice from now on. So the Snell function for exits 1,2, and 3 has value 6pm, since you can make this time. However, if you miss exit 3 for some reason then the Snell function deteriorates and it will be 6:45 as you approach exit 4. If you miss that exit also it deteriorates again. So it is giving you an upper bound on how well you can do from now on (how quickly you can get home), assuming you do the best thing possible, i.e not make any further mistakes.

The Snell function is a supermartingale because it never improves, it either stays constant or gets worse, when you can no longer achieve a solution as good as you could have chosen previously. That's inherent in the sequential nature of the decisions and the fact that "you can never go back" to an earlier time.

Comment: In Finance this can be applied for example to American option early exercise decisions. Getting off at the next exit => exercising the option at the end of today, staying on the highway => postponing the exercise.